# Internal error: Tried to take gradients (or similar) of a variable without handle data on running TF HUB BERT inside tf.GradientTape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to train [bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3) TF HUB model inside a persistent gradient tape in Tensorflow 2.4. The following is a simplified version of my code.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

input_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=4, dtype=tf.int32)
input_word_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=4, dtype=tf.int32)
input_type_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=4, dtype=tf.int32)

bert = hub.KerasLayer(
    "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3",
    trainable=True)({"input_mask": input_mask, 'input_word_ids': input_type_ids, "input_type_ids": input_type_ids})

dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(bert['pooled_output'])

encode = tf.keras.models.Model([input_mask, input_word_ids, input_type_ids], dense)
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros((1, 4))


@tf.function
def run():
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True, watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
        tape.watch(encode.trainable_weights)
        encode([data, data, data], training=True)


run()
```

**Error**

```
  raise ValueError("Internal error: Tried to take gradients (or similar) "

    ValueError: Internal error: Tried to take gradients (or similar) of a variable without handle data:
    Tensor("StatefulPartitionedCall:1079", dtype=resource)
```

This error is raised only when

- TF HUB trainable=True option is used
- persistent gradient tape is used.
  Is this a bug in TensorFlow or am I trying something which is not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using persistent GradientTapes for SavedModels requires TensorFlow 2.5+ both when saving and loading the SavedModel. Please follow along at https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/622 for updates on the release of TF2.5 and updated SavedModels for BERT etc.

The answer by M. Innat explains how to avoid the problem by using the standard, non-persistent GradientTapes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any need to use `persistent=True`, you should make it `False`. Typically it is set `True` when we need to calculate i.e losses inside the `tape` scope so that we can compute their gradients outside the scope, [src](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape). In your above code example, I think you don't need this.

Another typo in your code that may need to fix. It has one wrong input mapping.

```
bert = hub.KerasLayer(
    "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3",
    trainable=True)(
        {
           "input_mask": input_mask, 
           'input_word_ids': input_word_ids,  # < ---------
           "input_type_ids": input_type_ids
         }
     )
```

Running the code with these changes

```
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros((1, 4))

@tf.function
def run():
    with tf.GradientTape( watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
        tape.watch(encode.trainable_weights)
        y = encode([data, data, data], training=True)
    tf.print(y)

run()

# [[-0.799545228]]
```

Comment: I actually have two optimizers and want to call tape.gradient twice. This is the reason I am using persistant=True.